# jQuery.extend throws stack overflow exception with self references

Tags: javascript, jquery, stack-overflow, extend

I was working on a JavaScript application when I noticed that: using **[jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)** function has a special behaviour when used with object that have a reference to them self.

If you run [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8EN6f/) script:

```
var x = new (function(){ this.self = this });
var y = {}; y.self = y;

console.log($.extend(true, {}, x))
console.log($.extend(true, {}, y))
```

You will notice that the extending with 'x' works fine, while extending with 'y' throws a [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) exception.

Can you explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is whether the object is a plain object or not. `x` had a constructor; so when `extend` comes to the value of `self`, I suppose jQuery doesn't want to deep copy it, since it doesn't know that it can recreate it properly, and ends up with just a plain, non-deep copy for that attribute.

`y`, on the other hand, checks out as a POJO, and `extend` thinks it's okay to deep-copy it, which results in the infinite recursion.

Look at [`extend` code](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.extend), where it says "`// Recurse if we're merging plain objects or arrays`"

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `.extend()` does a deep copy of plain objects and arrays, but not a deep copy of function objects.

Since `x` is a function object, it doesn't do a deep copy of that.

But since `y` is a plain object, it does try to do a deep copy and runs into the infinite loop.

From the jQuery `.extend()` source:

```
// Recurse if we're merging plain objects or arrays
if ( deep && copy && ( jQuery.isPlainObject(copy) || (copyIsArray = jQuery.isArray(copy)) ) ) {
    if ( copyIsArray ) {
        copyIsArray = false;
        clone = src && jQuery.isArray(src) ? src : [];
    } else {
        clone = src && jQuery.isPlainObject(src) ? src : {};
    }

    // Never move original objects, clone them
    target[ name ] = jQuery.extend( deep, clone, copy );

// Don't bring in undefined values
} else if ( copy !== undefined ) {
    target[ name ] = copy;
}
```

You can see that it is checking to see if the property is a plain object or an array.  A function object will not be either.

Comment: Regarding `x`, where is the end of the circle, shouldn't it be recursive ?

Comment: @RCV - When `.extend()` looks at `x`, and it goes to copy the properties, it gets to the `.self` property, it sees that is not a plain object or an array so it does not try to do a deep copy of `.self`, thus it just copies the `.self` property over and goes on, never creating the infinite loop.  It is when it tries to do a deep copy of `.self` when copying `y` that it creates the infinite loop.  It would be possible to make a smarter version of `.extend` that could handle references within the copy, but it would be a lot of extra work.  jQuery went for a simplifying assumption.

Comment: @RCV - no there is no end in the debugger.  That's why doing a deep copy of `y` does stackoverflow.  I will repeat what I've said several times so far.  jQuery's `.extend()` does NOT do a deep copy of properties of a function object which is what `x` is.  If no deep copy, then no possibility of infinite recursion.